# .nc file can't be opened on multiple versions of ArcGIS Pro (2.9, 3.1, 3.1.2) nor QGIS. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, nc

I'm attempting to open and view this .nc file: https://sbclter.msi.ucsb.edu/data/catalog/package/?package=knb-lter-sbc.74 . I've used multiple methods, including multidimensional raster and NetCDF Table view to then use space time cube. Nothing is working. I've requested help from others and they have been able to open it using the latter method, but there are issues where the "time" variable is just not present when attempting to make a NetCDF Table View so I cannot make a space time cube.

The following is the screenshot of the person attempting to help me and what they see; the second screenshot is what I see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To add to this as the person working with Declan, this hasn't worked with any method in either Pro or QGIS and in any of the software versions. Can't drag and drop, add as a mesh layer, add as a multidimensional raster, etc. I have worked with many .nc files and this one is just stumping us. The link posted is to the data we downloaded. If anyone can figure out how to load this so the latitude, longitude, time, biomass, and area variables can be viewed, that would be very appreciated.